New to Ubuntu, a bit overwhelmed by help from "Ask Ubuntu" "Ubuntu in Launchpad" and Ubuntu Pro
I've been able to get previous versions of Ubuntu to work in a dual boot capacity before. I've also gotten Linux Mint to work successfully so I have some experience installing and using operating systems other than Windows.
Bottom line up front: I experienced several failed attempts to install 24.04. The Ubuntu installer automatically generated bug reports destined for "https://bugs.launchpad.net/". If the Ubuntu installer automatically sends me to launchpad to file my bug reports is there a collaborative relationship between "Ask Ubuntu" and Launchpad? Or do I need to ask the same question here to get an answer from "Ask Ubuntu"?
Basically I'm just trying to find some help installing 24.04 on my computer and I'm not sure where to go.
Thank you for your time.
CJ

As Quiverc stated in his answer Launchpad is for Bugs and AskUbuntu is for user to user support.  What he didn't state is that any StackExchange site that provides user-to-user support allows posters to say something like: I've looked for and found support for Issue  X and issue X is related to Bug Y.  Launchpad Bug Y to Post Issue X (going the other way) is not allowed as the relevant bug information should be stored in the filed bug.  User-to-user sites can help determine if Issue X should be a bug though.

@eyoung100; thank you!

Launchpad is a bug tracker (and far more actually) and is used largely by developers. Ask Ubuntu is a User Support (Q&A) site used by users. Yes there is some overlap (I use both, yet I'm no developer) but they run separate from each other, with most users not using both (ie. this is a end-user support, launchpad is a development tool).
If you use both (and you can) providing the launchpad ID/link is useful, but you should not expect users of one site to see details posted on the other very different purpose site.
Stack Exchange rules only disallow you asking the question on multiple Stack Exchange Sites (Ask Ubuntu being one such site), but there are no rules preventing you seeking support on this site (helping you!), and a seeking bug fix at the launchpad bug tracker (helping future users from avoiding your issue!).

I've voted to move (off-topic) the question to the meta site (as off-topic), but I think this answer fits meta anyway...

I don't think it's on topic on meta anyway, it isn't really asking about Ask Ubuntu, more about where one should go to get help for the Ubuntu OS, so I would argue it's off topic on meta.

Fair enough @terdon....  FYI:  My answer didn't address Ubuntu Pro, but that's a product offered by Canonical, the best place to look for details about Ubuntu Pro is the FAQ - https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-pro-faq/34042

Actually, products and services offered by Canonical are explicitly on topic. Frankly, I kinda wish they weren't, but that's my personal view, the reality is that they are.
